# Matlab: plotting a directed graph

Tags: matlab, plot

I'd like to draw a rectangular grid with arrows pointing from each cell to its 4 neighbors. It can also be a directed graph with nodes and labelled edges. Any suggestions to do this in a less tedious way?

Edit: I am not interested in exporting Matlab data to third party tools.

[image: mdpgrid]

Answer (score 1):

Use Matlab to write a `.dot` file that is then rendered with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with directed graphs:

It should be pretty straight forward to use [`biograph`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html) for this.

Hope it helps!

Edit:
I'm not sure if this is feasible in your case, but you can adjust the topology using `dolayout`.

```
   % Manually modify the node position and recalculate the paths.
   bg.nodes(1).Position = [150 150];
   dolayout(bg,'PathsOnly',true)
   view(bg)
```

If you create a function that assigns appropriate X,Y coordinates, you might achieve what you want.

-Rob

Comment: This is a very powerful command, thank you. The only problem seems that the rectangular topology cannot be achieved without manual adjustment which is a big problem in my case.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also, Graphviz has a function `rectangularLayout`, that would work well, but then again, that will be a third party tool.

Comment: Wow, TIL about "biograph".  Note that it requires the "bioinformatics toolbox".